# Sorting a CSV file numerically

Tags: python, csv, sorting

Is there any way in which I can sort a CSV file into descending order.

I have a CSV file which contains all the scores of different players. The code below pulls the first 5 scores from the csv file and outputs it on my program. However i would like the highest 5 scores to be outputted, not the first 5. Is there anyway in which I can do this.

```
   def DisplayLeaderBoard():        
        count = 0
        with open ('StudentNames&Questions.csv') as scorelist:
            reader = csv.DictReader(scorelist)

            for row in reader:
                if count ==250:
                    break
                count = count+50
                scores_label = Label(canvas, text=(row['Names'], row['Score']), bg = 'gray25', fg='snow', font = font1)
                canvas_scores_label = canvas.create_window(350, 280+count, window = scores_label, width = 500, height = 40)
```

I have played around with this code below, however this is used mainly for arrays. So if anyone knows how to put it first into an array and then into a for loop of labels then please let me know.

```
        array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: `x[0]` won't work here since you've passed a `DictReader`. Pass a `Reader` and convert to integer in your sort key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x[0]` won't work here since you've passed a `DictReader`, so the argument of `x` needs to be a column key, and also `csv` module doesn't convert numerical values back to integers, so you could end up with an alphanum sort on your integer-as-strings values.

To sum it up, you need to sort according to the *numerical value* of the "Score" column:

```
for row in sorted(reader,key = lambda x : int(x['Score']),reverse=True):
```